# If I book a return journey with Wizz Air and miss the first flight, can I still take the return flight?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, regulations, wizz-air

I have booked a Wizz Air ticket (RT 17-31/JAN) from the Netherlands to Bulgaria, but due to school I have to change the booking. What I noticed was that the rebooking fee is ridiculously high - €30 plus €10 for the fare. However, I have found an alternative flight (one-way 22/JAN) on a different reservation and it is only €20.

The dilemma is that I have to leave later than the original flight I have booked, so it means that I will not use the onward flight but will for sure use the return flight.

Do you know if Wizz Air has any specific policy to no-shows at airports etc?

Answer (score 17):

As with some other low-cost airlines (namely Ryanair), the word "reservation" applies to the one-way ticket per person. That is, if you bought the return ticket, you have made two "reservations". Similarly, if you bought tickets for several people, then you have several "reservations".

I confirmed this with Wizzair by phone and then I also did the exact thing you wanted: I bought another ticket for the outbound flight (another carrier, even) and then just used the return flight. Even more, we were in three to have booked together, and there was no impact on other travelers. That was August 2014.

But care should be taken if flying with infants : they are bound to the reservation and therefore cannot fly within another reservation if the reservation that was holding them is cancelled. So if you take infants on your name and you don't show up, the other passenger traveling with you cannot take them.