# starting a flight at a stopover point

Tags: air-travel, transit

I have a ticket from Larnaca Cyprus, via London to Houston. I no longer want to start my journey in Larnaca as I will be in London. Can I just get on the plane in London after the 10 hour layover at Heathrow. It's also a change of airline but on one ticket.

Comment: the simple answer is "no".  if you're no-show on the first leg, the whole thing is cancelled.  as others have said, this is an oft-repeated question

Answer (score 4):

The vast major of airlines do not allow this, but rather require you to have your ticket changed in such a case. They will cancel your ticket in case you don't show up for your first flight.

See the following threads for similar answers and more details:

- [Book connecting flight, but only board at second airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/book-connecting-flight-but-only-board-at-second-airport)
- [Is it okay to board only the second flight of a return ticket? The return ticket is much cheaper than buying one way](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18854/is-it-okay-to-board-only-the-second-flight-of-a-return-ticket-the-return-ticket)