# EasyJet - Is the return flight valid if I miss the first leg?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, missed-flights, easyjet

British Airways: [If I book a return journey with British Airways and miss the first flight, can I still use the return flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84939/if-i-book-a-return-journey-with-british-airways-and-miss-the-first-flight-can-i)

WizzAir: [If I book a return journey with Wizz Air and miss the first flight, can I still take the return flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/if-i-book-a-return-journey-with-wizz-air-and-miss-the-first-flight-can-i-still)

RyanAir: [If I book a return journey with Ryanair and miss the first flight, can I still take the return flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57879/if-i-book-a-return-journey-with-ryanair-and-miss-the-first-flight-can-i-still-t)

I'm flying with EasyJet and they didn't answer on Twitter yet: https://twitter.com/stefek99/status/891243760763494403

[image]

Comment: Have you tried that old fashion method of communicating - calling them?

Comment: I did open email, I did proceed to contact page. But that was on mobile and there was no phone number visible... I use telephone too.

Comment: @Tom this is the 21th century, what is this "calling them" you are talking about :P ?  Also check https://twitter.com/littlemxsurly/status/426026660857917440

Comment: @chx - And that device used to send tweets is called a p h o n e - a device that handles voice calls, voice - a built in human function used for thousands of years to communicate netween two humans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick search shows that they have [answered](https://mobile.twitter.com/davidarchbold1/status/334578377216364544?lang=en) to other users on Twitter, and the answer is **yes, it's valid**:

**Question from a user:**

> Is it still true that if I get to my destination another way (not
>   easyJet) I can still use the return leg of my booking?

**Answer from @easyJet:**

> Yes that's correct, even if you don't use your outbound flight the
>   return is still valid.

Comment: There had to be one advantage to them pricing every trip in terms of individual segments.