# Round-trip ticket and one-way ticket on the same flight

Tags: air-travel

This is the situation. 
I live in country X and my friend in country Y. 
My friend will visit me, so we looked for some round trip tickets for him to do so.
Now, immediately after his visit, I will visit him in country Y, so I will book myself some (say, one-way ticket) from country X to country Y, **exactly on the same date as his flight back home**.
As natural, we would like to fly together.
My question is

> Is there a way to get my one-way ticket from Y to X so that it coincides with his flight back home? (i.e. same connections, same planes)

What I've tried so far is simply to look for one-way flights from Y to X on that specific date (using the same search engine we used for his round trip tickets), but his flights are not showing up in the results!

Another solution we thought was simply buying together two round-trip tickets from X to Y, and I just simply wouldn't take the one from X to Y, but of course this is wasting money (considering we're talking about international flights).

My impression is that this situation is quite common, and maybe somebody knows a better solution.

Thanks!

---

I didn't know how to formulate the title of the question in a more explanatory way. 
I apologize for that. 
If somebody finds a better way of doing it please feel free to edit

Comment: What do you know about [code sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement)?  The flight may be known under another identifier when not booked exactly as he did.  Or it may simply be full

Comment: Can you provide details of the flight(s) and dates? How did your friend book his return ticket?

Comment: Did you try searching directly with the airline?

Comment: @ChrisH Hmmmm interesting. I guess I have seen it on the screens but didn't know it had a name, nor how it works. Thanks for the info! That could be indeed the case.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for the comment, but I'd feel more comfortable not sharing that information,as it shouldn't be relevant for the discussion. My question was a bit more general.

Comment: @Johns-305 The problem is that it was a non-direct flight with different airlines

Comment: "Another solution we thought was simply buying together two round-trip tickets from X to Y, and I just simply wouldn't take the one from X to Y, but of course this is wasting money (considering we're talking about international flights)."  Don't do that; they'll cancel your return ticket if you don't take the first flight:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18856/4171

Answer (score 3):

My boyfriend and I now have a set of tickets like the one you asked about, my A to B, together B to A, he A to B.
We did this by being on the same ticket selling site at the same time and making the booking at the same time, so we were both sure the booking was going through before either one committed.

This is just a single flight but working the same way would work for flights where you have to make connections as well.

As your friend already has his flights, you will need to search for the same flights. It does not need to be one way tickets, unless you do not want to return home.

If you can not get a ticket selling site to do it for you, try going to a travel agency, one that specializes in business travel may work for this.

You will still need to check in together and may still end up in different parts of the plane, although a good travel agency should be able to get you in the same fare class, so likely in the same part of the plane.

Of course, tickets not bought together give less guaranty of traveling together, but two (or more) adults traveling together will be separated if the airlines think it is needed. If one of you is asked to use a different flight, for whatever reason, volunteer to both change, if you can afford the delay in arrival.

As a side note: On checking in online, within a few minutes from each other, we found we were given seats next to each other, which was a nice surprise which we were not expecting.
We were expecting to change at least one of the check-in seats, ask at the airport or even fly in different parts of the plane.