# If I book a return journey with Ryanair and miss the first flight, can I still take the return flight?

Tags: ryanair, missed-flights

Does Ryanair have the sequential use of flight coupons rule?

Meaning if you miss any flight-segment on your itinerary all subsequent segments are canceled.

Does this rule apply if tickets are bought in one booking?

Comment: I've removed (subject to review) the "And what about other low-cost airlines?" part of the question. There are so many low-cost airlines in the world that asking about all their policies is far too broad.

Comment: Well, apparently, the reviewers didn't agree and "Please tell me the policies of hundreds of airlines" isn't too broad. \*boggle\*

Comment: For Wizzair see this Q: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11519/32134

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ryanair only sells one-ways or returns so the only case is missing your first flight and still wanting to take the return. That is possible without any actions necessary on your part as stated [here on their website FAQ](http://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/can-i-cancel-my-reservation-before-travel-and-do-i-need-to-notify-ryanair-if-i-am-not-travelling/):

> You don't need to notify us if you are unable to travel and if you can’t use  your outbound flight you can still use your return flight.

So yes, if you miss the first flight you can still take the return flight and no, there is no sequential use of flight coupons rule.

Comment: The question is "can I still take the return flight" and you answer "no" but mean yes?

Comment: That referred to the first sentence in the Q I guess "Does Ryanair have the sequential use of flight coupons rule?" but let me edit to clarify :)

Answer (score 4):

Most low cost airlines, including Ryan Air do sell each flight as individual item. Meaning that if one flight is late, you are not guarantied onward travel even if you have bought your tickets from the same site at the same time.

On the other hand, as each portion of the travel is an individual one way ticket, if you miss one flight but are in the right spot on the right time for your next flight, you can fly, as it is a separate flight.

I hope to add links to this answer, for now I am searching them.
No link with proof for the 'individual tickets' yet, but I found [one that states that there is a 'missed flight fee'](https://www.ryanair.com/us/fees/) looks like that for 100 euro or 100 pounds they might be willing to book you onto an other flight, which is an improvement over former policies